# How can I make Shift+End select text again?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> is supposed to select all the text from the current position to the end of the line.  For some reason my computer stopped behaving that way yesterday.  Now my cursor doesn't move when I click <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>.

More Details:

- Nothing happens when <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> is clicked
- The End button and other combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> work
- Other combinations like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> work
- Every application is affected
- Alas, a simple reboot did not fix the problem
- I haven't installed any new software recently

Any troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait... Rebooting DID NOT fix the problem?! I'm at a loss... I suppose the obvious question is: Did anything change yesterday before the problem arose? Install any software, configuration changes, etc?

Comment: Is there a difference if you use the left shift or the right shift?

Comment: have you confirmed that your keyboard layout is correctly detected? have there been any changes to your keyboard drivers in Device manager? have you tried unplugging it and plugging it back in have any impact?

Comment: Does your cursor move to end of line if you press `End` alone?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the Sculpt keyboard and I just updated the Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center hoping that it would fix the problem.  After the update, I noticed (thanks to new on screen notifications) that hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> would toggle the Scroll Lock.  This caused me to look at my <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key and notice that the bottom left corner was stuck down.  After fixing the key everything went back to normal.

Interestingly, now that the key is fixed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> no longer toggles the Scroll Lock.  It must be some sort of fall-back in case the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key is jammed.  I did a quick search but couldn't find any documentation on this.

**TLDR**: the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key was stuck but I didn't notice it.

Comment: fricken scrolllock. I used it once for CICS sessions in the late ninties and never since.

Comment: wierd. my shift+end wasn't toggling Scroll Lock, but toggling SL itself once actually fixed the issue.... o.O mysterious world

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that Num Lock key is turned on if your computer has number pad. For me it worked normal after pressing NumLock Key.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but it wasn't a stuck scroll lock key.

I use an Apple USB keyboard with my PC. And for some odd reason, even though I am able to see the actual <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> key input is working when using a keyboard input profiler, it fails to function for the purpose of selecting text from the cursor to the end of a line.

I was able to solve the problem by using EventGhost. Just needed to add a macro for the key combo to send the shortcut to the active app/window.

[image: EventGhost screenshot]

[image: AutoHotkey keyboard history screenshot]

Info on keyboard input profiling:

- Key History in AutoHotkey is accessible from double-clicking the system tray icon, or "Open" from it's right=click menu, then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
- EventGhost will log keystrokes in real time when using the "keyboard" plugin.